# Spark standalone files processing order degrades performance

Tags: apache-spark

Hi I am beginner to Apache Spark and has done a bit in it... Appreciate any help on below situation.

Step1: I am running a Spark standalone/local instance which is instantiated at run time from my maven build jar.
Step2: I am watching a folder for .gz(gunzip) files and reading them using javaSparkContext.textFile(logFilePath, partitionCount).map((final String line) code in java.
using .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());
Step3: All is working fine no issues with processing, what i am stuck with is a situation(processing order) which is explained below consider 50 gunzip(.gz) files of different size from 500KB to 250MB.
Category 1 : 10 files File 0f 500KB
Category 2 : 10 File - 1.5MB
Category 3 : 10 File - 8MB
Category 4 : 10 File - 108MB
Category 5 : 10 File - 248MB

Case/Situation: when processing File all 5 category files seperately then perfromance is good. but once put the all 5 category file in same folder and process them then the performance of the jar is like hell.
hardware used is 8core/32GB ram.
what iam getting from here is if file of different sizes are kept togeather and processed randomly. the perfomance is degarded almost 30times.

some statistics:
when processing category file separetely: average time is 20 minutes per file. but when same file is processed randomly time taken is more than 8 hours.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: can you post the code? What watching means in this case? Are you interested in compute something when a file is added to your directory or you want to read data from a folder?

Comment: Watching Folder here means looking for any gunzip(.gz) files in folder and picking the files on by one for processing.
please find below the piece of code

JavaRDD<Document> jRDDDocument = jsc.textFile(logFilePath).repartition(partitionCount).map((final String line) -> RDDProcessing.getLogAsDocument(line,pubAttrib,dateSet)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER());